# signalR connection breaks after redirection to another view in MVC3 app

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

I am trying to implement SignalR in my existing MVC3 application to send alerts to all connected client. I am using Persistent connection. Just to test this i have placed a broadcast button on _Layout page. Clicking on broadcast button sends some text using connection.send($(‘#msg’).val()); and is successfully received by the clients. But this only works when the message is broadcasted from first/default page when app loads. Once the page is redirected it looses the connection and on click of Broadcast button it throws error message “SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call .start() before .send()”. Please advice.
Here's the code in my sample application: Note that when i navigate from Home to About, the connection gets lost.

```
<head>
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var connection = $.connection('echo');

    connection.received(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });

    connection.start();

    $("#broadcast").click(function () {
        connection.send($('#msg').val());
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="msg" />         
<input type="button" id="broadcast" value="Broadcast" />
<ul id="messages"></ul> 
<div class="page">

    <div id="header">
        <div id="title">
            <h1>My MVC Application</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="logindisplay">
            @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
        </div>

        <div id="menucontainer">

            <ul id="menu">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        @RenderBody()
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your javascript using a tool such as firebug to see if the start() method is called?

Comment: Yes i did. It does calls Start() method. method is in the _Layout page and my about page uses the same _Layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The connection will only be alive as long as the client is "alive". If you refresh the browser it will open a new connection. The issue you might be having is with the url you passed to the connection ctor.

If you're not using hubs then you don't need the ~/signalr/hubs included in your page.

If you navigate to http://{siteUrl}/echo in a new browser window, what does it say?

You might need to do something like:

```
var connection = $.connection('@Url.Content("~/echo")');
```

But that's based on how you mapped the route.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. Do you have or point me to some code samples that i could refer to learn more about signalR?